# Win10 Wi-Fi > netsh wlan show profile > Cost not available

Tags: windows, wireless-networking

I'm trying to connect my laptop to my mobile Wi-Fi hotspot as a metered connection, but the cost state is "Not available" and I want to change to "Fixed" (metered).

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32>netsh wlan show profile name="Mobile Hotspot"

Profile Mobile Hotspot on interface Wi-Fi Intel_DBW:
=======================================================================

Applied: All User Profile

Profile information
-------------------
    Version                : 1
    Type                   : Wireless LAN
    Name                   : Mobile Hotspot
    Control options        :
        Connection mode    : Connect automatically
        Network broadcast  : Connect only if this network is broadcasting
        AutoSwitch         : Do not switch to other networks
        MAC Randomization  : Disabled

Connectivity settings
---------------------
    Number of SSIDs        : 1
    SSID name              : "Mobile Hotspot"
    Network type           : Infrastructure
    Radio type             : [ Any Radio Type ]
    Vendor extension          : Not present

Security settings
-----------------
    Authentication         : WPA2-Personal
    Cipher                 : CCMP
    Authentication         : WPA2-Personal
    Cipher                 : GCMP
    Security key           : Present

Cost settings
-------------
    Cost                   : Not available
```

BTW. The Settings UI that shows Metered Connection slide-button will not keep/stay on. It shows as **On**, but if I exit and come back it is **Off**.

> [image: Windows 10 Metered Network]

If I click "Set a data limit..." it goes to Network Status, and nothing on this page goes to or allows a limit setting:

> [image: Windows 10 Network Settings]

I do have **only** IPv4 and IPv6 enabled in Network Connection Properties:

> [image: Network Conn Properties]

Comment: The setting is gray which means it’s disabled which means the adapter likely doesn’t support metered mode.

Comment: Try re-enabling all protocol bindings.